# Does "APIs and Services" google sdk available for generating API keys?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-client

I am unable to find any client sdk for "APIs and Services" i want to create API KEY pragmatically which is located under credentials.  link https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials" . Is there is any rest API or SDK available.

Comment: Given the [strong guidance against using API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) (as opposed to service accounts) and the fact that there is only a documented mechanism to generate them using the console, I'd be surprised if there was a programmatic method to generate them.

Comment: Thank you @robsiemb I did my RnD and could not find any cloud SDK that's why I asked question I just wanted to make sure that i am not missing any thing.

Answer (score 1):

The API are private and you can't generate and validate by yourselves the keys.

I think that the main reason is the low level of security of API keys compare to OAuth2 token.

Comment: Perfect I just wanted to confirm that I am not missing this now I know thank you @guillaume blaquiere may be it would help someone else.